# fs.mkdir() and fs.writeFile() don't work in Glitch hosting

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, hosting, fs

I have a node app on glitch that has to create directories and files to store data, when I had it in Heroku all worked well, but now, I haved changed to glitch and it doesn't work. Reading the logs I think that Glitch don't allow my program to create folders and files, logs:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './files/665290737256103949'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:752:3)
at Object.execute (/app/commands/condenar.js:39:12)
at Client.bot.on.message (/app/index.js:106:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/68c8ba02-3c6e-4076-88e9-cde586593473/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/68c8ba02-3c6e-4076-88e9-cde586593473/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/68c8ba02-3c6e-4076-88e9-cde586593473/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/68c8ba02-3c6e-4076-88e9-cde586593473/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/68c8ba02-3c6e-4076-88e9-cde586593473/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './files/665290737256103949' }
(node:28673) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
(node:28673) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at item.request.gen.end (/rbd/pnpm-volume/68c8ba02-3c6e-4076-88e9-cde586593473/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (/rbd/pnpm-volume/68c8ba02-3c6e-4076-88e9-cde586593473/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:28673) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:28673) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:28673) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glitch does allow writing and reading of files. You should re look at what you have. In fact, glitch comes with fs built in so you dont even need to npm install it.